# View throttled WCF calls in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2013, throttling

How do I check for throttled WCF calls (or Tasks that async call WCF service) in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Why do you need to check that?

Comment: For load testing to get the point to scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with PerfMon. under **ServiceModelService** 3/4

**Percent Of Max Concurent Calls:**
Number of calls waiting to be or being processed in the dispatcher as a percentage of max calls throttle.

**Percent Of Max Concurrent Instances:**
Number of active instances and messages waiting for instances as a percentage of max instances throttle.